# How to design an IDE using Qt?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, ide, compiler-construction

My friends and I are working on a compiler design as a project in my university (Damascus University).

We're using (Flex, C++, Bison, Qt) to do the job.

I was wondering if there is a way to design an IDE to our compiler using Qt. I know how to do the job but I'm asking to find out if there is some resource to start with, or if there is a pre-built design to do that job.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just a small note: We don't want a full featured IDE, just a place for errors and a toolbar and some find/replace tool.
Something like Notepad++ would be great :D

Comment: Why don't you simply start from Qt's text editor example and add syntax hightlighting to it... that will give you something like Notepad++.

Comment: I have already done that :)
But I was wondering how to do more.

Answer (score 5):

Start by looking at the source code of [QtCreator](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator). It is very clean and easy to read!

Comment: There's no dispute that QtCreator is written nicely but it's a pretty big project. Even reading it to get ideas can be a daunting task for someone interested in making a small editor like the op requires. It supports things like version control, plugins, build systems...

Comment: I agree, I read some parts of it but I got lost wandering through its files searching for things I wanted and I couldn't find them!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already suggested QtCreator you could check the [qt-apps.org development environments](http://qt-apps.org/?xcontentmode=4260) website; a lot software there is open source

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extending KDevelop with a module would be a better idea. Qt creator is awfully focused on Qt. Other interesting starting points would be Edyuk (they've separated out their editor component from the rest of the application) or good old Scintilla (used by PyQt from Riverbank).

Comment: I wouldn't say QtCreator is awfully focused on Qt. If anything KDevelop is awfully coupled with KDE.